# Make typescript compiler not complain in Promise

Tags: typescript, promise

This is probably easy, but I am quite new to promises. My code is not compiling, how to change that:

```
public static sendTestEvent(): Promise<boolean> {
    let options: any = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};

    this.modifyEvent().then(()=> {
        return WebRequest.post(this.URI, options, JSON.stringify(this.eventToSend)).then((response) => {
            return browser.sleep(Config.EVENT_PROCESS_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
                console.log('resolved');
                return Promise.resolve(true);
            });
        });
    }, (err)=> {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    });

}

public static modifyEvent(): Promise<boolean> {
    let currentDate = new Date();

    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Event modified');
        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

I get 'Return statement is required for non-void return type'

Comment: sendTestEvent isn't returning anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what it looks like, you've told TypeScript that you're planning on returning something of type `Promise<resolving to boolean>` in the `sendTestEvent` method.  It looks like there is no return statement found in that method.  You should be able to fix this by returning the result of the `.then` method in that method.

```
public static sendTestEvent(): Promise<boolean> {
    let options: any = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};

    return this.modifyEvent().then(()=> {
//  ^^^^^^ return here
        return WebRequest.post(this.URI, options, JSON.stringify(this.eventToSend)).then((response) => {
            return browser.sleep(Config.EVENT_PROCESS_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
                console.log('resolved');
                return Promise.resolve(true);
            });
        });
    }, (err)=> {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    });
}

public static modifyEvent(): Promise<boolean> {
    let currentDate = new Date();

    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Event modified');
        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

That should fix the problem you're getting with the compiler.

Comment: Actually that was only partially true, the problem here was in the incompatibilities of .then, WebRequest.post method returned a Promise<Response<string>>, it occurred that removing then on that method solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have declared method as returning promise. So just return it:

```
public static sendTestEvent(): Promise<boolean> {
let options: any = {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};

return this.modifyEvent().then(()=> {
//...
```